# Command line tool to parse XML and run an XPath for CI/CD

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

For Maven projects running in CD, we often need to reference the current version of the project (I imagine this is a pretty universal problem for anyone doing Java builds)

For example, one may need to find an artifact pattern based on version or copy the artifact to a S3 bucket named after the current version declared in the POM

However, I've found it shockingly difficult to get data out of the POM. Best I could find was:

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -Ev '(^\[|Download)' > target/version.txt`

which seems hacky ...

is there a linux command line utility available through a package manager that can just parse an XML file and run a XPath? If such a thing does not exist, I might consider creating one

I am asking because I am surprised how frequently this feature is needed in builds and how little I was able to find in terms of a popular solution

Comment: Do you use Jenkins as CI/CD solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should configure to use [maven-help-plugin version 3.1.0](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/) and than you can get the version like this:

```
RESULT=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
echo $RESULT
```

Or you can also go the explicit way:

```
RESULT=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
echo $RESULT
```

More details can be found in [my blog](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/06/09/help-plugin/).